# Turn off screen by pressing the power button

Tags: power-management, acpi, button

Is there any way to configure the power button so it turns the screen off?
I now use a script running

> xset dpms force off

to turn off the screen.
Is it possible to edit

```
/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
```

so it turns off the screen?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use xdotool to assign commands to a keyboard button
for example : 
`xdotool key 121` 
assigns the command entered  to button F1

You first need to assign the command [xset dpms force off] to keyboard shortcuts [ex F1] found in: system settings -> shortcuts and gestures in kde

You even could trigger the command by drawing a mouse gesture ..

Also, this can be done easily in kde, system settings -> power management

[system settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCJ3g.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and effort. I know that using the keyboard is an option but I am so used to just press the power button from Windows that i want to make it work in Ubuntu as well. Nevertheless I will give your recommendation a try!

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to mention I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 ;)